# Why doesn't C# realise that this reference type variable is guaranteed to be set?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
private TestClass? getTestClass() {
    return new TestClass();
}

private void testMethod() {
    var testClass = getTestClass();
    var testBool = true;
    if (testBool) {
        testClass = new TestClass();
    }
    var someInt = testClass.IntMember;
}
```

The last line gives me a warning with nullable reference types: Dereference of a possibly null reference.

Why is this a possibly null reference?  `testBool` must be true, the if block must get run, and the variable must be initialized to non-null.  Oddly, if I change to `if (true)` it works.  Why doesn't `if (always-true-bool-variable)`?

Comment: Just to be clear: you want an explanation of the status quo, not a workaround for the situation shown, right?

Comment: Since you already know better than the analyzer in this case, just go ahead and remove the meaningless `if`. Thus, no problem.

Comment: While you are at it, your `getTestClass()` method shouldn't be declared to return `TestClass?`, it always returns a non-null value

Comment: This is just speculation, but I would assume there is a limit to how deep the IDE will follow things like this because I would imagine trying to evaluate uncompiled code would take a decent amount of resources for something that doesn't seem very worth it. It could also simply be that `testBool` technically gets set at runtime instead of compile time, so the intellisense doesn't bother trying to figure out what its value would be. Also, semantics, but it's not "C#" giving this message; it's the IDE. Using a different IDE may have different results.

Comment: As stated in the previous comments, there are limitation to the depth of the compiler. It gives you a warning, if you are sure that in your case this will never happen, you could simply surround your lines of code with `#pragma warning disable CS8602` and `#pragma warning restore CS8602`.

Comment: I haven't put it into sharplab, but wouldn't that be optimized away by the compiler anyway?

Comment: Why do you keep asking the same question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Null-tracking is very similar to definite assignment. As the unfinished [spec for nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/nullable-reference-types-specification#null-tracking-for-variables) says:

> For certain expressions denoting variables, fields or properties, the null state is tracked between occurrences, based on assignments to them, tests performed on them and the control flow between them. This is similar to how definite assignment is tracked for variables.

That section is unfinished, but there is a TODO at the bottom saying "describe null state transitions similar to definite assignment".

Let's consider a variation of your code - if `testClass` is initially "definitely not assigned", and you assign a value to it in the `if`, would `testClass` be "definitely assigned" after the `if`?

```
TestClass testClass;
bool testBool = true;
if (testBool) {
    testClass = new TestClass();
}
Console.WriteLine(testClass);
```

There is no definite assignment rule that says `testClass` should be definitely assigned after the `if`, and the last line above produces an error.

If `testBool` is a [constant expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1223-constant-expressions) (an expression whose value is known at compile-time, like the literal `true`) of value `true` however, `testClass` *is* definitely assigned after the `if`. See these two sections of the language spec [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables#94421-general-rules-for-constant-expressions), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables#9446-if-statements):

> For a constant expression with value `true`:
>
> - If `v` is definitely assigned before the expression, then `v` is definitely assigned after the expression.
> - Otherwise `v` is “definitely assigned after false expression” after the expression.

> For a statement stmt of the form:
>
> ```
> if ( «expr» ) «then_stmt» else «else_stmt»
> ```
>
> - If `v` has the state “definitely assigned after false expression” at the end of expr, then it is definitely assigned on the control flow transfer to else_stmt, and not definitely assigned on the control flow transfer to then_stmt. It is definitely assigned at the end-point of stmt if and only if it is definitely assigned at the end-point of then_stmt.

Basically, `if (testBool)` is not what you call "`if (always-true-bool-variable`". It *would have been*, if you had declared `testBool` with `const`.

```
const bool testBool = true;
```

Going back to null-tracking. The situation is basically the same if you just replace "definitely assigned" with "definitely not null". When the `if` condition is a constant expression of value `true`, and `testClass` is definitely not null inside the "then" branch, it is also definitely not null after the `if` statement. This is not the case, if the `if` condition is not a constant expression - nothing about the nullability of `testClass` after the `if` can be deduced, and the null state doesn't change.